# Click tracking on anchor links

Tags: civimail

We recently re-designed a regular e-mail to include a "menu" at the top.  The menu is a list of anchor links to sections further down the e-mail.  However, we are not seeing any clicks being tracked on these anchor links.  Is there a way to track these clicks?

Answer (score 4):

No. Links that do not go to a website cannot be tracked by CiviCRM. The reason is that anchor links simply scroll the document the user is reading - they will not take them to an external site, which is how CiviCRM does the tracking.